# Mongodump without mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Since it is possible to `mongodump`/`mongorestore` remotely, it makes sense to have them installed in a machine that is not the DB itself, right?

Is there a way to install a standalone `mongodump` executable?

Eg. in order to dockerize my DB backup tool

Comment: What O/S are you using? Official Linux packages (eg: [Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#packages) include `mongodb-org-tools` if you only want to install the command line tools. You can also copy the `mongodump` / `mongorestore` binaries from an existing install, but there may be missing library dependencies to install (eg. TLS/SSL).

Comment: Yeah, that sounds interesting. I want to dockerize my DB backup tool so Ubuntu is really fine. I'll give it a try and report.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ubuntu has the tools separate: `mongodb-org-tools`
Alpine also has an edge/community package: [`mongodb-tools`](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mongodb-tools)

I am using the node:alpine Docker to run mongodump/restore and upload to S3, it works well.

You could also try installing and then copying the binaries, but I imagine they have a lot of dependencies so you might as well find a way to use the tools package, or you'll be creating your own.

Answer (score 11):

Accepted answer did not work for me on a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.04.

```
E: Unable to locate package mongodb-org-tools
```

Following the instructions on the [official MongoDB page](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) worked.

Note that instructions are for installing MongoDB and optionally the tools. If you just want `mongodump` you can follow steps 1 to 3 and then run `sudo apt install mongodb-org-tools`

Here are the 3 steps for reference (Ubuntu 20.04, tested on 22.04):

1. Import the public key used by the package management system:

```bash
sudo apt-get install gnupg curl

curl -fsSL https://pgp.mongodb.com/server-7.0.asc | \
   sudo gpg -o /usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg \
   --dearmor
```

2. Create a list file for MongoDB:

```bash
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/mongodb-server-7.0.gpg ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu jammy/mongodb-org/7.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-7.0.list
```

3. Reload local package database

```bash
sudo apt-get update
```

Then install the tools:

```bash
sudo apt install mongodb-org-tools
```

Comment: I also had to run 'sudo apt install gnupg'

Answer (score 8):

`mongo-tools` since Ubuntu 18.04: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/bionic/+package/mongo-tools

```
sudo apt install mongo-tools
```

Answer (score -4):

You can perform backup of remote cluster using mongodump.
  Command is :

/path/to/mongodump --host remote_cluster_hostname --port remote_cluster_port>

For Installing only mongodump utility below steps can be performed:

Step 1: Install Mongodb rpm, but don't start mongod process.

In a linux system if you have installed mongodb using rpm package, you should not start mongod process.
You can find the location of mongodump using this command: `which mongodump`
  And use mongodump to perform remote backup.

Step 2:Use Zip packages of mongodb binaries instead of installing mongodb on server.

Download mongodb Zip packages and extract the zip. You can find all the mongodb binaries inside the zip folder.
  Use mongodump to perform remote backup. In this way you don't need to follow installation steps of mongodb server and utilities.

Comment: What you suggest doesn't feel like an official solution. Of course I can install mongodb without running it, but that's a lot of overload. Say I want to create a docker out of it, it won't be lightweight.